# Is it possible to increase the number of visible tabs in MacVim (without changing the window width)?

Tags: macvim, tabbed-user-interface

The question is more or less in the title, until recently I have the feeling that I got a fairly large number of visible tabs in any window of MacVim. I either updated MacVim or my system or something and now I can only get 5 visible tabs in a 90 character wide window. Is there any way to increase this number?

I'm using MacVim Custom Version 8.0 (113), if that helps.

To better explain what I mean I have attached a picture, I have opened six tabs but only five are visible (called one, two, three, and so on). The sixth and all subsequent tabs are inside the >>. I'd like to be able to have more than 5 tabs visible at any given time.

[image: Picture of the problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the minimum width of a tab is configurable, and set by default to 120 (pixels). It can be redefined by doing:

```
defaults write org.vim.MacVim MMTabMinWidth 55
```

where 55 is the minimum width of a tab in pixels. This allows me to get 11 tabs in a window of 90 characters, which solves my problem.

Comment: In case anyone's wondering: It appears that you have to restart the MacVim process for this change to take effect, it's not a dynamic value that is changeable at runtime, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

There's the `tabpagemax` option that limits the number of tab pages you can open with `$ vim -p *.txt` to `10` by default. But you can create as many tab pages as you want with `:tabnew` or `:tabedit`.

Which is one of the reasons why using tab pages as file proxy is a very bad idea.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not answer my question. I am not asking about the maximum number of tabs it is possible to open, I am asking about the number that are visible before the >> in the picture I just added to the question. There are are 5 visible tabs called "one", "two" etc, and I want to know if it is possible to show more than 5 without them going into the >>

Comment: [Here](http://imgur.com/a/nFTfV) I can get to 13 before the *dreaded* `>>` appears. It's *almost* as if the maximum number of tabs is determined by the available width.

Comment: Sure, but I used to be able to get more tabs in a window with a fixed width of 90 characters.